# Upgrading react-script creates error "no elements in sequence"

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, jestjs, react-scripts

I upgraded react-scripts to 4.0.3.

My react test now results in a error of `message: 'no elements in sequence', name: 'EmptyError'`. Seems to point towards the below code as the issue:

```js
    receiver$
      .pipe(
        filter(message => message.requestId === requestId),
        first()
      )
      .subscribe(
        ({ success, data, error }) => {
          if (success) {
            // console.log(`data for - ${serverCommand}`, data);
            resolve(data);
          } else {
            console.log('rejecting this got data ', data, error);
            reject(error || data);
          }
        },
        error => console.warn('Caught error in make request', error)
      );
  });
```

i have tried replacing `first()`x with `take(1)` but still no luck. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm surprised `take(1)` doesn't work. At first blush nothing else jumps out as being wrong.

Comment: If this error is thrown by this code snippet then using `take(1)` would definitelly not throw this type of error. `'no elements in sequence'` is only thrown by operators like `first()`, `last()` etc..